# Find words in a cell and return a true or false using regexract

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to find words in a cell using regextract but it is not bringing back all words in the cell.

It will bring back:

```
gamer
```

but not

```
_gamer
```

or

```
@gamer
```

But I need all of them. [Here is the sheet I am using.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ouZ-oMoeXZqwRZIhOAbN_OJS7inbW0kqRF438BuNXzY/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to find words in a cell using regextract but it is not bringing back all words in the cell:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C3,"gamer|gaming|game")
```

true

Comment: you want included @ and _ when outputing gamer too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), 
 IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(A1:A, ".*game.*|game|.*gaming.*|gaming")), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, ".*game.*|game|.*gaming.*|gaming")))
```

[image: 0]